# How to remove character from list in dictionary in python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
my_dict = {'name1': [1, 2], 'name2': [2, 3], 'name3': [3, 0]}
```

I want remove the square brackets so that it looks like this

```
my_dict = {'name1': 1, 2, 'name2': 2, 3, 'name3': 3, 0}
```

My script below so far results in a 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object':

```
my_dict = {re.sub(r'[\w]+','',k):re.sub(r'[^\d]+','',v) for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: A dictionary is a set of Key : Value pairs. If you remove the list [] brackets, there are two values for each key, which is not a dictionary. You can keep the list, or you can create a tuple, or some object type. But there must be only one value.

Comment: Or do you want to transform the lists to strings, like `{'name1': '1, 2', 'name2': '2, 3', 'name3': '3, 0'}`?

Comment: `{k:', '.join(map(str, li)) for k,li in  my_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 1):

The sequence `[1, 2]` (if your representation of the data is correct) is a list of ints.

If you do string like functions on a list of ints, you will get a type error:

```
>>> import re
>>> li=[1, 2]
>>> re.sub(r'\[', '', li)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Instead, you need to convert the elements into strings:

```
>>> list(map(str, li))
['1', '2']
```

Then use `.join` to turn the list of strings into a single string:

```
>>> {k:', '.join(map(str, li)) for k,li in  my_dict.items()}
{'name1': '1, 2', 'name2': '2, 3', 'name3': '3, 0'}
```

Comment: Thanks for this response!

Answer (score -1):

Bah! This works

new_dict = str(my_dict).replace("[" , "").replace("]","")